# Public transporation from Kansai Airport to Osaka

Tags: public-transport, japan, airport-transfer, osaka, kix

What is the public transportation from Kansai Int'l airport to  Minami district of Osaka?

Comment: "The cheapest and easy way" to do what exactly? This question is far too broad to answer. If you have a specific question like "how do I get from point A to point B?", then edit your question and let us know.

Comment: Regarding the edited question, there is nothing like a "Minami district" in Osaka city. Do you mean Minami-ku of Sakai city?

Answer (score 5):

If by Minami you mean the Southern area of Osaka, in the sense described by [Japan Guide](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e4001.html), you're probably looking to go to Namba.

From Kansai you have a few options, you can take the Nankai-Kuko line, the Nankai Limited Express or JR Kansai Rapid Service. These will cost you anywhere between ¥920 to ¥1400, unless you have the JR pass which makes the trip free (except for the subway, if you decide to take that in the city)

[image: hyperdia trip]
[image: nankai ltd express]
[image: nankai kuko]